# button on click is triggered twice on safari iOS

Tags: jquery, safari, mobile-safari

I'm designing a web app.

On chrome browser all works fine but on safari iPad, the on click method for a button is triggered twice when I click once.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've fixed my problem thanks to this http://www.danwellman.co.uk/fixing-jquery-click-events-for-the-ipad/